# Usage difference between "Have got" and "Have gotten" in AmE

Tags: have-got, got-gotten

In the following AmE examples:

(a) I have contacted them. I haven't got their answer
(b) I have contacted them. I haven't gotten their answer

My first interpretation would be that in (a) I could have obtained an answer, but I don't have it handy, whereas in (b), the answer was never received.

Is this a correct interpretation of the difference between these two examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for noting the possible duplication. I read that article before posting and I didn't feel the article reflects the specific case. Additionally, the article seems to be closed to further comments (or I'm not sure how to add to that article).

Comment: You need some reputation to post a comment.  5 or 10 points.